# Convert an array of objects to another array of objects using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am getting a result in my JavaScript file which I want to convert into another object.

My original result:

```
 results = [{Key1:'Value1', Key2:100, Key3:'A'},
            {Key1:'Value1', Key2:40,  Key3:'B'},
            {Key1:'Value2', Key2:60,  Key3:'A'},
            {Key1:'Value2', Key2:70,  Key3:'B'},
            {Key1:'Value3', Key2:50,  Key3:'A'},
            {Key1:'Value3', Key2:90,  Key3:'B'}];
```

Convert this to look like an array of objects using jQuery or JavaScript. How can I achieve this?

```
finalResult=[{Key1:'Value1', A:100, B:40},
             {Key1:'Value2', A:60,  B:70},
             {Key1:'Value3', A:50,  B:90}];
```

Comment: Well Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service so it is up to you to show us what you tried so we can help you fix **your code**

Comment: Why the objects are enclosed `(` &  `)` instead of `[` & `]`

Comment: @brk Because he doesn't know how an array literal looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the array incorrectly, and you need to replace the outer `()` by `[]`, like

```
var results = [ {}, {} ];
```

You need to first make a map of different `Key1`'s

```
var map = {};
results.forEach( function(item){
   map[ item.Key1 ] = map[ item.Key1 ] || {};
   map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] = map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] || 0;
   map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] += item.Key2;
})
```

Now iterate the keys of this map, and prepare your output

```
var output = Object.keys(map).map( function(value){
    var obj = { key1 : value };
    Object.keys( map[ value ] ).forEach( function(key2){
        obj[ key2 ] = map[ value ][ key2 ]
    });
    return obj;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var results=[
  {Key1:'Value1',Key2:100,Key3:'A'},
  {Key1:'Value1',Key2:40,Key3:'B'},
  {Key1:'Value2',Key2:60,Key3:'A'},
  {Key1:'Value2',Key2:70,Key3:'B'},
  {Key1:'Value3',Key2:50,Key3:'A'},
  {Key1:'Value3',Key2:90,Key3:'B'}
];
var map = {};
results.forEach( function(item){
   map[ item.Key1 ] = map[ item.Key1 ] || {};
   map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] = map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] || 0;
   map[ item.Key1 ][ item.Key3 ] += item.Key2;
});

var output = Object.keys(map).map( function(value){
    var obj = { key1 : value };
    Object.keys( map[ value ] ).forEach( function(key2){
        obj[ key2 ] = map[ value ][ key2 ]
    });
    return obj;
});
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
let results=[{Key1:'Value1',Key2:100,Key3:'A'},
         {Key1:'Value1',Key2:40,Key3:'B'},
         {Key1:'Value2',Key2:60,Key3:'A'},
         {Key1:'Value2',Key2:70,Key3:'B'},
         {Key1:'Value3',Key2:50,Key3:'A'},
         {Key1:'Value3',Key2:90,Key3:'B'}];
         
let finalResult = [];
for (let original of results) {  
    if (!finalResult[original.Key1]) {
        finalResult[original.Key1] = { Key1: original.Key1 };
    }

    finalResult[original.Key1][original.Key3] = original.Key2;
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group objects based on the `Key1` value. Then using `Object.values()`, you can get the accumulated result of each key.

```js
const input = [{Key1:'Value1',Key2:100,Key3:'A'},{Key1:'Value1',Key2:40,Key3:'B'},{Key1:'Value2',Key2:60,Key3:'A'},{Key1:'Value2',Key2:70,Key3:'B'},{Key1:'Value3',Key2:50,Key3:'A'},{Key1:'Value3',Key2:90,Key3:'B'}];

const result = input.reduce((r, {Key1, Key2, Key3}) => {
  r[Key1] ?
      r[Key1][Key3] = Key2
    : r[Key1] = {Key1, [Key3] : Key2 };
  return r;
},{});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```